# Multiple commits in vuex action not triggering mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm attempting to set a loading status on a component which will display a loading graphic while the request is being processed. I have this working with a call to an API, returning a promise from a fetch to a REST interface. However, when attempting this with a simple call to a service it only seems to call the last mutation

In the vuex store:

```
var initialState = {
    status: { loading: false },
    all_clients: [],
    current_client: {
        loaded: false,
    }
}

export const fund = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: initialState,
   actions: {
        getClientOverview({ commit }, client_group_id) {
            commit('loadingRequest');

            clientService.getClientOverview(client_group_id)
                 .then(
                     clientInfo => {
                        commit('loadingSuccess')
                     },
                     error => {
                        commit('loadingError', error);
                    }
                 )
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        // Mutations to set loading and error statuses
        loadingRequest(state) {
            state.status = { loading: true };
        },
        loadingSuccess(state) {
            state.status = { loading: false };
        },
        loadingError(state,error) {
            state.status = { loading: false };
            store.dispatch('alert/error', "Error Loading Client: " + error)
        },        
   }
```

and in the corresponding client service that is called:

```
function getClientOverview(client_group_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        try {
            // Note here that client.state.all_clients is an array of objects already set in the store

            let clientDetail = client.state.all_clients.filter(function(item) {
                return item.client_group_id === client_group_id;
            });

            // THIS PAUSE CODE JUST ADDED TO SLOW THINGS DOWN A BIT ON FRONT END 
            // SO I CAN SEE IF MUTATIONS ARE WORKING CORRECTLY
             var d = new Date();
             var d2 = null;
             do { d2 = new Date(); }
             while(d2-d < 2000);
            // TO HERE

            if(clientDetail.length == 0){
                reject("Client Information not found")
            }
            resolve(clientDetail[0])
        }catch(error){
            reject(error)
        }
    })
}
```

A client is being returned as expected, as a resolved promise, but I only see 'loading' being set to false on the front end, it doesn't set to true while the service is running its process.

If I remove the commit('loadingSuccess') line then I can see the original commit being called as expected and loading being set to true - it seems as though only one commit is being called per action

Any help with this would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using vue devtools in the browser to view the commits being made? There shouldn't be any reason for adding a pause to know if it worked or not. The culprit could be that you're essentially freezing the app for two seconds before resolving. Does it behave differently if you wrap the `resolve` in a `setTimeout` instead?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me- I was seeing the mutations make the state change in the vue dev tools. I've just reloaded with using the `setTimeout` functionality instead of the time loop I'd written before - that seems to be the issue - many thanks for the quick response. All working now as expected